# Error in predict() glmnet function: not-yet-implemented method

Tags: r, glmnet

When i use the predict glmnet function, i get the error mentioned below the code.

```
mydata <- read.csv("data.csv")
x <- mydata[,1:4]
y <- mydata[,5]
data <- cbind(x,y)
model <- model.matrix(y~., data=data)
ridgedata <- model[,-1]
train <- sample(1:dim(ridgedata)[1], round(0.8*dim(ridgedata)[1]))
test <- setdiff(1:dim(ridgedata)[1],train)
x_train <- data[train, ]
y_train <- data$y[train]
x_test <- data[test, ]
y_test <- data$y[test]
k=5
grid =10^seq(10,-2, length =100)
fit <- cv.glmnet(model,y,k=k,lambda = grid)
lambda_min <- fit$lambda.min
fit_test <- predict(fit, newx=x_test,s=lambda_min)
```

The error is as follows:

> Error in `as.matrix(cbind2(1, newx) %*% nbeta)` :    error in evaluating
> the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.matrix': Error
> in `cbind2(1, newx) %*% nbeta` :    not-yet-implemented method for
> `<data.frame> %*% <dgCMatrix>`

I tried debugging, but i am not sure where the

> as.matrix(cbind2(1, newx) %*% nbeta)

code is being used and what is causing this error.

Comment: try `x_test <- as.matrix(data[test, ])` ?

Comment: @BenBolker Getting the same error

Comment: OK, then we need a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) please ...

Comment: Can you post a version I don't have to request access for, i.e. completely open?  Even better, can you create a small self-contained example that generates the same error and can just be posted here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your original data frame has a factor (categorical) variable among the predictor variables.  When you use `model.matrix` it does something sensible with this variable; if you just pass it directly to `predict`, it doesn't know what to do.

```
newX <- model.matrix(~.-y,data=x_test)
fit_test<-predict(fit, newx=newX,s=lambda_min)
```

By the way, you could have replicated this example with a minimal/made-up example, with just a few lines of data ... for example, this setup gives the same error (I called the data `dd` rather than "data", because the latter is a built-in function in R):

```
set.seed(101)
dd <- data.frame(y=rnorm(5),
            a=1:5,b=2:6,c=3:7,d=letters[1:5])
model <- model.matrix(y~., data=dd)
n <- nrow(dd)
train <- sample(1:n, size=round(0.8*n))
test <- setdiff(1:n,train)
```

Comment: That was very helpful indeed. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks. Does this mean that I can't use categorical variables with cv.glmnet? I am running against the same issue, I am using nummerical variables except one (gender). Thankks in advance!

Comment: Another question: could you explain the meaning of "~."? [tilde followed by dot]

Comment: it means that you need to convert your categorical variables to dummy variables, which is most easily done using `model.matrix`. The formula `y~.` says to include all the variables in the data frame, except for the response variable, in the model matrix

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. However, I still don't understand since x does not contain the response variable. Aren't we dummifying only the predictor to dummies (and not the y)? Another question is that using glmnet one can use categorical variables, but not using cv.glmnet, which is strange (just to be sure, I am talking about the upper example, with the minus sign, which I don't know what is doing either).